# pandas: merging dataframes, one has multiple indices

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataset which I merged together but got eroneous results.

so I created wo small dataframes to perform my merge but I am getting  incorrect answers and most times, errors.

```
a = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(3,4),columns=['a','b','c','d'])
b = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,0,0,1],'b':[1,2,3,4],'c':[1,1,2,2],'d':[11,22,3,44]})
```

These are simple examples.

```
e=b.set_index(['a','b'])
```

I Want to merge dataframes: a and c
using inner join, with the column `a` on `a` and the indices `a` and `b` on `c`...

How is this possible?

Comment: So what is desired output?

Comment: I tried pd.merge(a,c,how='inner',left_on='a',right_index=True) but I keep getting an error, I would want it in such a way that the dataframe 'c' does a left join on dataframe 'a'

Comment: It didnt work, so, is it better to leave the dataframe as b, merge dataframes a and b, then set the index??

Comment: If you need join on multiple columns, maybe you need: `print pd.merge(a, b, how='inner',left_on=['a', 'a'],right_on=['a','b'])`